# Problems with JSON decode in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, pytest

I'm tryin to run python tests with pytest in Docker container and one command not working in container when I build it:

```
file = open(f'..\\data\\file.json', 'a+', encoding='utf-8')
file.seek(0)
requests.post(url=SOMEURL, json=json.loads(file.read())) #it not works
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTvWa.png)
*""Decode a JSON document from `s` (a `str` beginning with
a JSON document) and return a 2-tuple of the Python
representation and the index in `s` where the document ended.
This can be used to decode a JSON document from a string that may
have extraneous data at the end.*

But it works in pycharm interpreter on Windows system! Where is problem?

Docker image from Docker hub: python:3.10.4-slim

Run command:

```
RUN ["pytest", "-v", "--junitxml=reports/result.xml"]
```

File content:

```
{
    "field" : "field_content",
    "size" : 1000000,
    "another_field":"content"
}
```

Comment: The backslashes won't work in a Linux container; consider using [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to build up the path in an OS-independent way.  The error you show seems to be a docstring rather than an actual exception; do you have the actual exception?

Comment: Container sees the file. Exception is: """
     try:
             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
         except StopIteration as err:
           raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
           json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

 /usr/local/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py:355: JSONDecodeError